# My manager is causing company losing business opportunity

Tags: teamwork

**Background:**
I am Asian. One of the asian value at least my family and my surrounding is `pay back and obey` and it is considered as a `value` or `loyalty` to your parents and your boss. If I lacks it I might not be able to be trusted by people around me.

My manager has no actual software skills and keep trying to do the job with his own style therefore budget spending going up software is buggy and unmaintainable. Company keep losing business opportunity for a year because of late delivery. By doing that company gave him warning challenge once in the annual meeting mentioned he is putting company to the line. I confirm 2 persons. I and buddy can delivery this entire project with in 1 or 2 months, but his team spend almost 2 years already... No delivery...

**Situation:**
I got hired by him and his team, but later on I found that his management causes company losing business opportunity
For example

1. My team can deliver the feature, but he reject and dissolve my team because his junior team can not understand my code. And later he issue and wrong requirement that does not fit with business
2. He is not good team player
3. Issue wrong requirements. It is a consequence of 2nd issue then he can not find the accurate detail. I know because I do cross check with business team

**My Understanding:**
I have an answer with strategic move on this, but at least I would like to know from forum. It might be an never ending question from my culture and environment, but with Western or Europe I believe that I will found an alternative better answer

**Questions:**
1. Protect him or company?
2. If protect company means he and his team get fired. Am I evil?

Comment: This question is extremely unclear.  What exactly is it your boss is doing?  If it's like, he comes in an hour late to work, that's not such a big deal and you can (and should) leave it alone.  If it's like, he's stealing money from the company, then probably you should report it.

Comment: @Ertai87 I have updated my question. Please check

Comment: Who is the "he" in "he has no skills"?  Also, what leads you to think that he is intentionally harming the company, rather than just being incompetent?

Comment: @BenBarden Simple. If you are hired to do a cooking then you supposed to do be able to cook. If not or being incompetent you should step down and let other people lead the way and learn from them

Comment: With respect, it may be a big mistake to think of your company as worthy of your deep loyalty. The same is true of your present supervisor. This guy isn't your scatterbrained nephew, he's just a fellow employee. Even if he needs fixing, **it is not on you** to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like the company knows what's going wrong with your manager and they're on top of it.  You don't need to do anything.

I wouldn't say something like "I can do this project in 1 month", because then not only are you making your manager look bad, which isn't going to be good during review time, but also you're now making a promise to have this project done in 1 month.  Then maybe you run into some issues you didn't know before, and then when the project takes 3 months then you look like a fool and you broke your promise.  Let the company deal with your manager any way they want, it's not your business and you should not get involved.

Comment: Yes! Do nothing is my option that I have been using since this dispute started
And I agree to stop bad mouth about my optimistic estimation. I and my buddy are frustrated since our performance is based on team success. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

I believe that doing the righteous thing is more honorable than doing the traditional.  Too many bad people have hidden behind the protection of social rules keeping people quiet.  Loyalty is is earned, not a function of a title.  If this person does not deserve loyalty, I would not give it.

If you feel that the punishment from the truth coming out fits what the manager has done, then I see no moral issue in exposing him.  But you must also decide if the risk of being labeled disloyal will punish you more than you deserve to be punished.

Ultimately, you have to decide for yourself, but doing what is right for the right reasons cannot be considered "evil."

Comment: Thank you. I like you answer. But checking the correct mark might discourage new answer. Please wait for a short peroid